If $F \in C(a,b)$ is the antiderivative of f everywhere except one point, then F'=f for that point as well
Specifically: If $F'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in (a,c) \cup (c,b)$, and $F,f$
are both continuous over $(a,b)$, then $F'(c)=f(c)$ as well. (No knowledge of definite integrals should be used.) Note that the conditions say nothing about the existence of $F'(c).$
I have tried expanding all continuity and derivative conditions into the definitions, but couldn't proceed from there.

Hint: use L'Hopital's rule.

As the comments suggest you could use L'Hopital's rule. L'Hopital's rule, however, is more or less a slightly more advanced application of the mean value theorem. For the proposition you'd like to prove you can just as well use one of the simplest versions of the mean value theorem.

Concretely let $\varepsilon > 0$. By continuity of $f$ and the fact that $F'=f$ on
$(a,b)\setminus\lbrace c\rbrace$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|F'(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon$ for all $x \in I:=(a,b)$ with $0 < |x - c| < \delta$. Let $0 < \delta' \leq \delta$ be chosen so that $c + h \in I$ for all $h \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|h| < \delta'$. For $h \neq 0$
with $|h|< \delta'$, $F$ is continuous on $[c, c + h]$ (or $[c + h, c]$ if $h < 0$) and differentiable on $(c, c + h)$ (or $(c + h, c)$). By the mean value theorem, there exists a $\xi_h$ between $c$ and $c + h$ such that
$$
 F'(\xi_h) h = F(c + h) - F(c).
 $$
Note that $0 < |\xi_h - c| < \delta$ so that
$$
 \left| \frac{F(c + h) - F(c)}{h} - f(c) \right| = |F'(\xi_h) - f(c)| < \varepsilon.
 $$
Consequently
$$
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(c + h) - F(c)}{h} = f(c),
 $$
which means that $F$ is differentiable at $c$ with $F'(c) = f(c)$.
